# Limit of empty sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, summation

Why MMA delivers this result and how to interpret or reformulate it?

[image]

```
Limit[k Sum[1/i, {i, 1, k - 1}], k -> 0]
```

I would expect 0 as it is an empty sum.

MMA 12.1

---

###### Edit:

Both expressions below deliver the same results for n>0. By which formula MMA calculates the value -1 for n=0? In case of analytic continuation there should be a formula that I couldn't find. What does this formula look like?

[image]

I have answered by own question, see [below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250260/69288).

Comment: Analytic continuation of harmonic numbers. Your sum isn't actually empty, but goes from $1$ to $-1$ in the sense of analytic continuation.

Comment: Indeed, `k* Sum[1/i, {i, 1, k - 1}]` performs $k H_{k-1}$.

Comment: On other hand, `Sum[1/i, {i, 1, -1}]` equals `0` and `HarmonicNumber[-1]` is `ComplexInfinity` and `0*HarmonicNumber[-1]` performs `Indeterminate`.

Comment: @user64494 that's precisely why I mentioned [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: I don't find in the documentation to `Sum` something similar to `Sum[...,{i,1,-1}]`.

Comment: `Sum` treats `k` as a generic, discrete, integer variable. Then `Limit` treats `k` as a continuous variable (and Roman's comment applies). Besides `0` is not a limit point of the integers, so the limit as `k -> 0` is undefined. As represented in the given code, it's an ill-posed problem. This seems to achieve what you had in mind: `Block[{k = 0}, k Sum[1/i, {i, 1, k - 1}]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Harmonic number $H_{n-1}$ can be expressed by the [Digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers) function $\psi(n)$ together with  the Euler-Mascheroni constant  $\gamma\approx 0.5772$.

$\psi(n)=H_{n-1}-\gamma$

In MMA $\psi(n)$ and $\gamma$ are called by `PolyGamma[n]` and  `EulerGamma`.

```
Table[Limit[(PolyGamma[k] + EulerGamma)*k, k -> n], {n, 0, 4}]
*( {-1, 0, 2, 9/2, 22/3} *)
```

The limes is only necessary for $n=0$, i.e.

```
Table[(PolyGamma[n] + EulerGamma)*n, {n, 0, 4}]
(* {Indeterminate, 0, 2, 9/2, 22/3} *)
```

An expression (inspired from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971782/digamma-series-representation)) that delivers values for all integers $n\ge 0$ without using `Limit` or control commands is

$H_{n-1}=(n-1) \left(1+n \sum _{i=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{i (i+n-1)}\right)$

```
Table[(n-1)(1+n*Sum[1/(i(n-1+i)),{i,2,\[Infinity]}]),{n,0,4}]
*( {-1, 0, 2, 9/2, 22/3} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why MMA delivers this result?

To see more clearly what's happening, let's do one function per line.

`Limit[k Sum[1/i,{i,1,k-1}],k->0]` is the same as

`f1=Sum[1/i,{i,1,k-1}]` $=H_{k-1}$

`f2=k f1` $=kH_{k-1}$

`f3=Limit[f2,k->0]` $=-1$

The basic issue is Mathematica evaluates the `Sum` first assuming it is not empty. This is indeed an issue you can encounter in Mathematica and can be a bit annoying. The basic issue is `Sum` will give a general form assuming some things about your variables. You can explicitly see these assumptions by using `GenerateConditions`. Consider the following:

`Sum[1/i,{i,1,-1}]` $=0$

`Sum[1/i, {i, 1, k-1}]` $=H_{k-1}$

`Sum[1/i, {i, 1, k-1}]/. k->0` $=$ `ComplexInfinity`

`Sum[1/i,{i,1,k-1},GenerateConditions->True]` $=H_{k-1}\text{ if }k\in \mathbb{Z}\land k\geq 2$

`Sum[1/i,{i,1,k-1},GenerateConditions->True]/. k->0` $=$ `Undefined`

> and how to interpret or reformulate it?

I've encountered this a few times in the past and never found an elegant solution. What I ended up doing was just defining the special cases separately. For your case that's simple. Just plug in $k=0$ initially:

`With[{k = 0}, k Sum[1/i, {i, 1, k - 1}]]` gives 0.

In more complicated situations you can use `Piecewise`, `If`, or `Condition` to control the evaluation at a lower level.

Comment: `Sum[1/i, {i, 1, -1}]` produces `0` without ant `With`.

Comment: I'm aware, it's the first example I gives under "Consider the following:". I was just showing the more general form - it's good to avoid hard-coding variables when possible.

Comment: I don't find in the documentation to `Sum` something similar to `Sum[...,{i,1,-1}]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the relevance of that is?

Comment: bRost03 (@ does not work.): You wrote in your answer "`Sum[1/i,{i,1,-1}]`$=0$". Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I assume it's not in the documentation because it's fairly common knowledge that the empty sum is $0$ and follows from basic properties of sums. It's empty because $\sum_{i=a}^b$ means $i$ takes on values $a\leq i \leq b$ and there are no values of $i$ such that $1\leq i \leq -1$.

Comment: Sorry, I prefer arguments over emotional words.

Comment: I'm not sure how my words were emotional, but I legitimately don't understand the source of your confusion. Please elaborate and I'll give you a detailed argument. Do you not buy that the empty sum should be 0? Or that it's common knowledge that the empty sum is $0$? Or that $\sum_{i=a}^b f(i) \ ; \ b<a$ is empty? Or that `Sum[1/i,{i,1,-1}]` is empty? Or what?

Comment: Sorry, your statement " it's fairly common knowledge that the empty sum is 0 and follows from basic properties of sums." is not grounded. I don't find it in the documentation. Can you give a reference? TIA.

Comment: I'll admit it is less clear cut than I was thinking and it depends on how you define a sum. Wikipedia defines a finite sum by $\sum_{i=a}^b g(i)=0$, for $b < a$ and $\sum_{i=a}^b g(i)=g(b)+\sum_{i=a}^{b-1} g(i)$, for $b ≥ a$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition). However, in the same article they also say (5th identity in General identities section): $\sum_{n=s}^t f(n) =\sum_{n=s}^j f(n) + \sum_{n=j+1}^t f(n)$ which contradicts their own definition. So I'll concede it's not obvious and the documentation should make clear which convention they use.

Comment: Empty sums are explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum). More generally, when there is an identity element for a given algebraic structure and operation, that element is taken as the result of performing the operation with no operands.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman explains the contradiction by a generic result of `Sum`. There is a way to avoid any contradiction:

```
Sum[1/i, {i, 1, k - 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[HarmonicNumber[-1 + k],  Element[k, Integers] && k >= 2]`

Comment: I don't find in the documentation to `Sum` someting similar to  `Sum[...,{i,1,-1}]`.